# IE issue for jQquery dialog with transfer effect

Tags: jquery

I wrote a code to have transfer effect work with jQuery dialog. I test the code it works fine in IE, FF and Chrome. I post my code to StackOverflow for some kind of fine tuning and the developer Mr Frédéric Hamidi did some modification on my code to achieve what I was looking for.

Here i am giving my url from where anyone can see how my code works: http://jsbin.com/amicev/2  Please go to this url and see the effect.

Mr Frédéric Hamidi did some modification like

```
dlg.dialog("open").dialog("widget").css("visibility", "hidden");
$(this).effect("transfer", {
to: dlg.dialog("widget"),
className: "ui-effects-transfer"
}, 500, function() {
dlg.dialog("widget").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

after this some modification I found it works according to my requirement but nothing happen when I am testing the code in IE. In other browser it is working. I just could not understand that why output is not coming in IE. I am using IE version 8.0.7600.16385.

Mr Frédéric Hamidi said he test this code in IE 8 and it works on his end. I think my browser is also ok there is no bug.

So here I am giving the url where Mr Frédéric Hamidi change the code which is not working in IE 8 at my end. The url is http://jsbin.com/amicev/5/edit#preview

Please see the code and tell me why it is not running in my IE 8.